# How to add pip to path

Tags: python, path, pip

I used cmd and did pip install requests. However when I go to write my code it gives me an error that I don't have a module named requests but when I run pip list in cmd it says it in the list.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same python installation for both the script and pip

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: `pip --version` & `python --version`

Comment: my pip version is 19.2.3 and my python version is 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage your Python modules and projects is using Anaconda. Install Anaconda for Windows and you can create `Virtual environments` for individual projects that is a good practice. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have the library in the environment you are using. If you are using a IDE like pycharm ensure under interpreter you have the library there.

I dont think the issue is not having pip in your path.

Comment: How can I check if I have a library in the environment and if not how to make one?

Comment: I do have something called pycharm community edition set up im not sure.

Comment: Open pycharm. Navigate to new project. Name the project whatever you want. There should be a drop down menu titled "Project interpreter". Select existing interpreter radio button then in the drop down list pick your current install of python. Hit create. Now you have a folder called PyCharmProjects somewhere. Find it and it will have all your current projects. If you have any work already done (i.e. any .py files) copy them into the project you just made. Also, with pycharm you usuall dont need to use pip. Navigate to project interperter settings and hit the add button and find your lib.

Comment: I dont have it set up yet. I only got IDLE and Visual Studio 2019 but I do have Pycharm but not set up